# ¿Cómo puedo extraer texto con unas condiciones de inicio y fin dadas?

Tags: python, regex, archivo

Buenos días cordial saludo, estoy intentando seleccionar unos datos de un archivo en formato .g01 Los cuales contienen el siguiente patrón:

## Sta/Elev= xx número

(Aquí van unas parejas de números)

## Mann

Y esto se repite en n ocasiones, lo que necesito, es agrupar esa pareja de números encerradas en ese intervalo y crear un array con ellos, por ejemplo tengo esto:

```
Type RM Length L Ch R = 1 ,2655    ,11.2,11.1,10.5
XS GIS Cut Line=4
858341.2470677761196439.12427935858354.9998313071196457.53292637
858369.2753539641196470.40256485858387.8228168661196497.81690065
Node Last Edited Time=Aug/05/2019 11:42:02
#Sta/Elev= 245 
       0 2191.01      .8 2190.54     2.5  2189.4       5 2187.76     7.2  2186.4
     8.2 2185.73     9.5 2184.74    10.1 2184.22    10.3 2184.04    10.8 2183.55
    12.8 2180.84    13.1 2180.55    13.3 2180.29    13.9 2179.56    14.2 2179.25
    14.5 2179.03    15.8 2178.18    16.4 2177.81    16.7 2177.65      17 2177.54
    17.1 2177.51    17.2 2177.48    17.5 2177.43    17.6  2177.4    17.8 2177.39
#Mann= 3 , 0 , 0 
       0      .2       0    22.9      .2       0      43      .2       0
Bank Sta=22.9,43
XS Rating Curve= 0 ,0
XS HTab Starting El and Incr=2175.68,0.3, 51 
XS HTab Horizontal Distribution= 0 , 0 , 0 
Exp/Cntr(USF)=0,0
Exp/Cntr=0.3,0.1

Type RM Length L Ch R = 1 ,2643    ,7.3,8,8.6
XS GIS Cut Line=4
858331.4128970441196449.04549587858348.4099654481196465.98514562
858360.1686662441196476.05297462858380.9077539031196504.05908314
Node Last Edited Time=Aug/05/2019 11:42:02
#Sta/Elev= 268 
       0 2189.91      .3 2189.61      .9 2188.87     1.3 2188.44     2.4 2187.32
     3.1  2186.5     3.7 2185.71     4.4 2184.72     5.2 2183.55     5.6 2183.14
     5.9 2182.71     6.3 2182.33     6.6 2182.04     7.4 2181.36     7.7 2181.07
       8 2180.77     8.7 2179.92     9.5 2179.11    10.2 2178.55    10.8 2178.16
    10.9 2178.13    11.2 2177.97    11.5 2177.86    11.9 2177.75      13 2177.52
    13.7 2177.44    14.5  2177.4    15.7 2177.42    16.5 2177.38    16.6 2177.38
    16.9 2177.38    17.2 2177.38    17.2 2177.39    17.3  2177.4    17.6 2177.42
    17.9 2177.44    17.9 2177.45      18 2177.45    18.6 2177.46    18.7 2177.46
    19.3 2177.48    19.4 2177.48    19.7 2177.47      20 2177.44      20 2177.43
#Mann= 3 , 0 , 0 
       0      .2       0    23.7      .2       0    42.8      .2       0
Bank Sta=23.7,42.8
XS Rating Curve= 0 ,0
XS HTab Starting El and Incr=2175.57,0.3, 55 
XS HTab Horizontal Distribution= 0 , 0 , 0 
Exp/Cntr(USF)=0,0
Exp/Cntr=0.3,0.1
```

Quiero entonces como les mencioné las parejas de números que están en los intervalos de State/Ele y Mann, esto es lo que he desarrollado de código pero no me arroja lo que quiero:

```
import re

with open('a.g01','r') as file:
    file_contents = file.read()
    #print(file_contents)

try:
    found = re.search('#Sta/Elev=(.*)#Mann',file_contents, re.DOTALL).group(1)
except AttributeError:
    found = '' # apply your error handling

print(found)
```

Pero no me arroja lo esperado, agradezco cualquier ayuda al respecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por empezar, ajustaría mejor el patrón de búsqueda/captura por esto:

```
regex = r"Sta\/Elev= (.*?)#Mann"
```

Primero, hay que escapar la barra mediante `\/` para que sea considerada literalmente y luego hacemos una búsqueda del tipo "lazy" o perezosa `(.*?)` de cualquier caracater entre `Sta/Elev=` y `#Mann`, el modo tradicional es "greedy" o codicioso, que capturaría todo el contenido entre el primer `Sta/Elev=` y el último `#Mann`, lo cual no es lo que quieres. Adicionalmente hay que configurar el motor con: `re.DOTALL` para tratar todo como una única línea.

Entonces, el código de búsqueda/captura podría quedar así:

```
regex = r"Sta\/Elev= (.*?)#Mann"
matches = re.finditer(regex, file_contents, re.DOTALL)
if matches:
    valores = list(m[1] for m in matches)
    print("".join(valores))
else:
    print("Match not found")
```

Finalmente con `list(m[1] for m in matches)` elaboramos una lista con cada uno de los elementos capturados.

El anterior código solo es compatible con Python 3.6 o superior, si no es tu caso puedes probar con:

```
matches = re.findall(regex, file_contents, re.DOTALL)
if matches:
    print("".join(matches))
else:
    print("Match not found")
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu aporte, quería decirte que evalué tu código y me sale el siguiente error: '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not subscriptable
 no comprendo a que se deba, agradezco tu ayuda

Comment: @JulianAndresLastraGarcia, de casualidad estas usando una version de python  inferior a la 3.6?

Comment: sí, estoy usando la 3.5

Comment: Ok, verifica la última edición y cualquier cosa me dices.

Comment: Muchas gracias, cualquier cosa te vuelvo a molestar, valoro enormemente tu aporte.

Comment: Gracias me ha corrido bien, por ultimo y agradecer tu colaboración enorme, quería preguntarte como puedo esos str tomar los valores, separarlos en formato float y crear una lista de vectores así?

Comment: Haces un `split("\n")` de cada cadena, eso genera una lista con cada línea, en la primera tienes el valor de `#Sta/Elev=`, luego cada linea es una fila de la tabla de datos, por cada una de esta puedes hacer otro `split(" ")` y ya tienes una nueva lista con el valor de cada columna. Pruebalo, sino cualquier cosa  haces otra pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: @JulianAndresLastraGarcia La mejor forma de agradecer una respuesta útil es marcarla como aceptada (y si quieres también darle un voto positivo)

Comment: soy algo novato, pero creo que ya le dí me gusta, de verdad lo aprecio, Patricio quería preguntarte lo siguiente: realicé una parte de lo que me dijiste y me creo una lista dentro de otra lista, pero ahora esta tiene vacios, como puedo quitar dichos vacios? este es el código: x=[] for j in range (0,len(matches)):
    x.append(matches[j].split("\n" and " "))